# String-array in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, string, kotlin, android-resources

Begin new project in Kotlin and missing those.

Try to get string-array recources but can't.

In strings.xml I palced next items.

```
<string-array name="themeList">
    <item>white</item>
    <item>sepia</item>
    <item>black</item>
    <item>pink</item>
</string-array>
```

In code I try next:

```
val res: Resources = resources
val appThemeList = arrayOf(res.getStringArray(R.array.themeList))

for (value in appThemeList) {
    Log.i ("value", value.toString())
}
```

But in logCat i see:

```
I/value: [Ljava.lang.String;@40145f2
```

And I don'r understand, what I do incorrectly.

Comment: I used this concept as follows successfully: ```private var list= mutableListOf<String>("")
list = resources.getStringArray(R.array.string-array-list-name).toList() as MutableList<String>```

Answer (score 24):

replace

```
val appThemeList = arrayOf(res.getStringArray(R.array.themeList))
```

to

```
val appThemeList = res.getStringArray(R.array.themeList)
```

In other case you got array

```
 val myArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.themeList) //already array
```

And added to another array

```
 arrayOf(myArray) // array of arrays
```

Answer (score 9):

In android is depend on **context** when **outside** Activity like this

```
val themes = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.themeList)
```

or **without context** is direct to resource when **inside** Activity

```
val themes = resources.getStringArray(R.array.themeList)
```

Answer (score 3):

As we know `res.getStringArray` return `arraylist` so you do not need to write `arrayOf` on your code.

Simple way to achieve your goal is:-

```
val list = res.getStringArray(R.array.list);
```

We can use arrayOf when we have to define our array or we have already arraylist like below :-

```
val myArray = arrayOf(4, 5, 7, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 val Lines = Arrays.asList(resources.getStringArray(R.array.list))
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin use :

```
var yourVar = resources.getStringArray(R.array.your_string_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, also need to use context like below

```
var arry = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.your_string_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

With this line of code you get exactly the element in the place of index.

```
val the_string = resources.getStringArray(R.array.YOUR_STRING_ARRAY)[index].toString()
```

> **This will be your res/values/strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="YOUR_STRING_ARRAY">
    <item>kJ</item>
    <item>kWh</item>
    <item>Btu</item>
    <item>kcal</item>
</string-array>
```

> As an example if the index is 1 then the return value is "kWh"

Answer (score 0):

If you want use the path of resources in `RecyclerView.Adapter` Class you must put into function `onBindViewHolder`

```
val myItem = holder.itemView.resources.getStringArray(R.array.myItem_string_array)
```